# Forzar skip de publicidad videojs

Tags: videojs

en la compañía tuvimos un problema al estar usando JwPlayer, están cobrando cerca de $2000 us mensuales, como pueden ver es un valor muuuy alto. Conseguimos una opción que se llama VideoJs. Utilizamos VAST de google.

Algunas agencias envían sus VAST y colocan el tiempo para el skip, pero hay otras que simplemente no lo hacen, existara alguna manera con IMA o con contrib-ads de "forzar" o establecer por defecto un tiempo de skip cuando este no venga en el VAST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La [documentación](https://support.google.com/authorizedbuyers/answer/2691733?hl=en) de VAST IMA dice que el intervalo de segundos del skip no es configurable y es de 5 segundos.
No parece ser algo que se maneje desde el reproductor VideoJS.

En la documentación también indican que:

> How are skippable ads served?
>
> When a skippable ad is served, the publisher player reads the VAST
>   response to determine if the ad has been implemented correctly as a
>   skippable ad and then displays a skippable button. The ad will be
>   displayed for at least five seconds before it can be skipped.

Es decir que del lado del reproductor se lee lo que se recibe de VAST y, si trae la etiqueta de skippable, se muestra el botón de `Skip>>`. Para Video.js, el [plugin relacionado](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima) y el [core plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads) para mostrar ads, no hay ningún método o parámetro que configure esa propiedad del lado de quien pone el reproductor (o sea, tú).

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Hay algo que no comprendo bien, en el VAST (que es un archivo XML, tengo entendido) se debe de agregar una etiqueta de skip con el tiempo de duración, por ejemplo 5 segundos. Hay veces que viene y otras que no. Cuando esta no viene el prerroll dura 30 segudnos por ejemplo y no tenemos la opcion de mostrar un skip hasta que termine.

Comment: En la documentación enlazada explican cómo en VAST se configura esa reproducción. Debe llevar un parámetro que lo marque como skippable (depende de la versión de VAST) y lo añade el dueño del video: _"Creatives must include..."_

Comment: entiendo lo que me dices, pero sucede que el Tracking event="skip" no viene, es decir no lo implementan.

Comment: Por eso. No es configurable por quienes despliegan el ad, sólo por los creativos.

Comment: y nosotros que desplegamos el ad, podemos de alguna forma forzar a que aparezca el skip si este no viene configurado previamente por los creativos?

Comment: Hice más amplia la respuesta para que sea claro que no hay forma.

Comment: impecable amigo, graciass